# How can I use FontAwesome icons in NavigationPages UWP Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms, font-awesome, xamarin.uwp

I'm using FontAwesome in ContentPage, without any problem in Android and UWP. ( Android uses label rendering class).
However when I replace NavigationPage with ContnetPage, UWP font icons disappears and shows me a square!
Android is working fine with NavigationPage.
Is UWP needs rendering like Android ?

```cs
public class FontAwesomeIcon : Label
    {
        public const string Typeface = "FontAwesome";
        public FontAwesomeIcon(string fontAwesomeIcon = null)
        {
            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.Windows :
                {
                    FontFamily= "Assets/Fonts/FontAwesome.ttf#FontAwesome";
                    break;
                }
                case Device.Android :
                {
                    FontFamily = Typeface;
                    break;
                }
                case Device.iOS:
                {
                    FontFamily = Typeface;
                    break;
                }
            }
            Text = fontAwesomeIcon;
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get more icons from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/
        /// Tip: Just copy and past the icon picture here to get the icon
        /// </summary>
        public static class Icon
        {
            public static string AngleRight = "\uf105";
            public static string User = "\uf007";
            public static string Lock = "\uf023";
        }
    }
```

**Update :**

The answer is we must use this `FontFamily=@"/Assets/Fonts/FontAwesome.ttf#FontAwesome"`

Answer (score 1):

> However when I replace NavigationPage with ContnetPage, UWP font icons disappears and shows me a square! Android is working fine with NavigationPage. Is UWP needs rendering like Android ?

You have two ways using a custom font in your uwp client project.

Creating a custom renderer for `FontAwesomeIcon` class. And then set `FontFamily` for native control. Please reference the following code. Notice that you need to check the path of `FontFamily`.

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomLabel), typeof(CustomLabelRenderer))]

namespace FontAweSomeTest.UWP
{
    public class CustomLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var label = Control;
            string font = "Assets/Fonts/fontawesom-webfont.ttf#FontAwesome";
            label.FontFamily = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.FontFamily(font);
        }
    }
}
```

The other way is that you mentioned in your post. I have modified your code. Please check.

```cs
public class FontAwesomeIcon : Label
    {
        public const string Typeface = "FontAwesome";

        public FontAwesomeIcon(string fontAwesomeIcon = null)
        {
            switch (Device.OS)
            {
                case TargetPlatform.Windows:
                    {
                        FontFamily = "Assets/Fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf#FontAwesome";
                        break;
                    }
                case TargetPlatform.Android:
                    {
                        FontFamily = Typeface;
                        break;
                    }
                case TargetPlatform.iOS:
                    {
                        FontFamily = Typeface;
                        break;
                    }
            }
            Text = fontAwesomeIcon;
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get more icons from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/
        /// Tip: Just copy and past the icon picture here to get the icon
        /// </summary>
        public static class Icon
        {
            public static string AngleRight = "\uf105";
            public static string User = "\uf007";
            public static string Lock = "\uf023";
        }
    }
```

I replace NavigationPage with ContnetPage. And it is working pretty well.

Comment: Both of them not working on NavigationPage.
I'm using "FontAwesome.ttf", because my font file is "FontAwesome.ttf" in the Assets/Fonts folder ...

Comment: I found my answer. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Could you please share the solution with me? So that other users who come cross this issue can have a reference.

Comment: I am wondering the difference between string type `@" "` and `" " `?

Comment: Ye , me too. Probably it's a bug.